# How do I check the version of aws ec2 I am running?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have the following `Dockerfile` with this content:

```
FROM nginx:latest
```

I build and push this file to ECS. then I created task definition with own private key and service for running the container.

I want to access the container. so I follow after [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance-connect.html):

```
$ ssh -i myapp-nginx.pem ec2-user@my-ip-from-ec2
```

but when I loggedin, I get this message

```
   __|  __|  __|
   _|  (   \__ \   Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.i
 ____|\___|____/
```

So, I'm not sure I'm loggin to the container because:

```
apt-get not working. -> -bash: apt-get: command not found
lsb_release not working -> `bash: lsb_release: command not found`
```

So, my question is how do I know what OS I'm working on for [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel6-nginx)? and why I don't have ubuntu system?

Answer (score 2):

- You already wrote the version. You are running the Amazon linux AMI, a flavor of linux created by Amazon itself. See the documentation here: [Amazon linux AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/).
- You don´t have apt because you are using Amazon linux AMI, that uses yum as package manager.
- You are not inside the container. To enter the container you need to use docker exec. If you don´t have experience with it you will need to do some homework.
- The nginx container itself, according to the documentation in their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/baa050df601b5e798431a9db458e16f53b1031f6/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile), is using debian-stretch- slim (FROM debian:stretch-slim). So this is the "OS" that nginx is living in.
- Last but not least, if you want to have let´s encrypt certificates out of the box, I would recommend using a container that includes it, like the one [linked here](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt/), provided by linuxserver.io and including nginx.